# Datasource JNDI configuration in Tomcat 7.0 for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, datasource

When Datasource is configured in (tomcat 7) server.xml or in Context.xml, hibernate is not able to identify JNDI and throwing below excpetion but same is working fine when I tried to access datasource using JNDI in the code. What am doing wrong

**Below is my configuration in hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.pool_size 10
hibernate.dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.connection.datasource java:comp/env/jdbc/employee
hibernate.show_sql true
hibernate.format_sql true
```

in server.xml

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>
    **<Context docBase="hibernate" path="/hibernate">
            <Resource name="jdbc/employee" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:45000/hibernatetest"
          username="user" password="hibernate" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"/>
        </Context>**
  </Host>
```

In Context.xml file

```
    **<Context docBase="hibernate" path="/hibernate">
        <Resource name="jdbc/employee" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:45000/hibernatetest"
          username="user" password="hibernate" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"/>
    </Context>**
```

Finally below is my web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
    **<web-app >
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>edu.experiments.web.EmployeViewer</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/employee</url-pattern>        
        </servlet-mapping>

        <resource-ref>
            <description>DB Connection</description>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/employee</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
    </web-app>**


org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/employee]
```

Comment: Take <Context> out of server.xml entirely. Also, when you say "context.xml" do you mean META-INF/context.xml within your webapp, or do you mean Tomcat's global conf/context.xml?

Answer (score 4):

It is simpler than it may seem:

1. don't put anything about JNDI in your web.xml
2. in the context.xml you are using (whether global or webapp relative) use the proper name, say "jdbc/employee"
3. to hibernate configuration pass the name in the form "java:comp/env/jdbc/employee"

Here is the reference page:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html